# Как я могу завершать/приостановить выполнение кода/программы нажатием на определенную клавишу?

Tags: python

```
c = 0

while True :
    c = c + 1
    print(c)

    if c == 10 :
        break
    else :
        continue
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать библиотеку keyboard.

```
 import keyboard

 while True:
   if keyboard.is_pressed("w"):
     print("кнопка w нажата - цикл прерван!")
     break
```

Answer (score 1):

Остановить выполнение можно нажав <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: А возобновить выполнение?

Comment: В принципе, можно поймать исключение и перевести код в другое состояние, но вообще лучше такие исключения не ловить, конечно.