# как остановить запущенный файл в кмд?

Tags: python

у меня вопрос как остановить запущенный питоновский файл в кмд?
к примеру я сделал бота аиограм запустил его в кмд и не могу остановить...

Comment: Что такое "кмд"?

Comment: очевидно это "cmd".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как я могу завершать/приостановить выполнение кода/программы нажатием на определенную клавишу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406382/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%

Answer (score 0):

Остановка работы в терминале:

комбинация клавиш "Ctrl + C"

Поправочка: это для windows

Comment: не только для ms/windows